# TypeError: L.Control.Draw is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, ionic2, leaflet.draw

I wanted to draw a polygon in the leaflet map in my ionic2 app, for that I found leaflet-draw pluggin, but I am getting this error
TypeError: L.Control.Draw is not a constructor

My code looks this

```
this.map = L
  .map("map")
  .setView(this.latLng, 13)
  .on("click", this.onMapClicked.bind(this))

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
  .addTo(this.map);

this.marker = L
  .marker(this.latLng, { draggable: true })
  .on("dragend", this.onMarkerPositionChanged.bind(this))
  .addTo(this.map);

var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
this.map.addLayer(drawnItems);
console.log(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({

  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  }
});
this.map.addControl(drawControl);
```

Comment: [`Leaflet.draw`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) is a plugin. It's not part of the Leaflet core. Have you followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#install) and have you included the appropriate JavaScript file?

Comment: I did follow the installation instruction. But to be able to use it from my typescript code I installed the typings for leaflet-draw and included in my class via the reference path: /// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/leaflet/index.d.ts" />. Is there anything that I am missign here

Comment: Also when I debugged it from my chrome browser, I saw that L.Control is a function defined in leaflet typescript file, while in leaflet-draw typescript file 'Control' is a name space, inside which Draw is defined, so I think that this piece of code is not referring to currect 'Control'

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine. Could you show where/how you are importing Leaflet.draw? The error you mentioned looks like a runtime error - not a TypeScript error - right?

Comment: I would try to get the Leaflet bits working without TypeScript. Add TypeScript once you have the basics working.

Comment: Reference path that I mentioned earlier is where it is getting imported. This I have used in my class from where I pasted the code. Now the namespace 'L' is being used on both the file belonging to Leaflet and Leaflet-draw. This looks to me as a runtime issue and I think it might have to do with compile order. Not sure.

Comment: @user1791252, Any solution? I'm facing the same issue. It appears the typings for leaflet-draw are not complete.

Comment: 4 years later and I'm still running into this. Didn't have the issue until I began using the ts-loader, for some reason.

I noticed that if I 'console.log' Leaflet (L) and/or and LD (leaflet-draw) after importing them, the problem is solved. This seems to imply a race condition. I'm wondering if there is asynchronous code run in leaflet-draw but haven't checked into it yet. If so, the problem might be solved by an 'await'

Answer (score 25):

You need add to head html [CDN's](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#cdn's)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
```

and add to map `{ drawControl: true }`

```js
var map = L.map('mapid', { drawControl: true }).setView([25, 25], 2);
```

Comment: Missed this myself! Thanks. I think the problem is that the documentation doesn't specify that you need to import the script, to me it seemed like it was already included in the leaflet.js

Answer (score 6):

You can get the latest version of `leaflet.draw` from the following address

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet.draw

#### Version 1.0.4

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi To add leaflet draw into the Ionic or Angular application need to follow a few steps.
Hope you have already installed the leaflet.

1. `npm install leaflet-draw`
2. include **leaflet.draw.css** file in the **angular.json** file.
   [image]
3. import leaflet-draw in your angular component.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who uses **NPM** and **TypeScript**
(Basically, the problem is that you are missing the Leaflet-Draw library)

Install packages and types

```
$ npm i -S leaflet
$ npm i -S leaflet-draw
$ npm i -D @types/leaflet
$ npm i -D @types/leaflet-draw
```

Update your *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    types: [
      "leaflet",
      "leaflet-draw",
      ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Angular and i resolve importing the libraries in this way

```
import * as leaflet from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-draw';
import '@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free';
```